# Installation of pythontex

Tags: installing, python

I am trying to install `pythontex` on Ubuntu 13.04. but cant find the way how.
Downloaded ZIP from http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pythontex.

Tried to follow instructions but unfortunately something went wrong.

Is there any simpler way to do it?
If not, can you please help me by writing instructions step by step?

RE-EDITED:
After installing pythontex when I try to compile e.g.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{pythontex}  
\listfiles  

\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}  
def fib(n):    

a, b = 0, 1  
for i in range(n):  
a, b = b, a + b  
return a  
\end{pycode}  

\end{document}
```

I get error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment pycode undefined.  
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.  
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{pycode}.
```

*File List*
article.cls 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
utf8.def 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
t1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
ot1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
omsenc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
amsmath.sty 2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
amstext.sty 2000/06/29 v2.01
amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
amsbsy.sty 1999/11/29 v1.2d
amsopn.sty 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
amsfonts.sty 2009/06/22 v3.00 Basic AMSFonts support
amssymb.sty 2009/06/22 v3.00
pythontex.sty

---

Comment: Where did the installation go wrong?  You need to install things in the right directories.

Comment: There is no pythontex.sty so according to instructions (pythontex.pdf) I should start pythontex.ins and get pythontex.sty if understand it correctly. But I can't get pythontex.sty from it. So downloaded .sty from and start pythontex_install_texlive.py. It gives me some options during installation and don't know what to do with it.

Comment: That's not enough: you need to install many different files for pythontex to work.  See the [README](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/pythontex/README).  You should download the entire zip file (direct link: [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pythontex.zip)]).

Comment: unfortunately, don't know how to do it. after unzip I've got pythontex.sty from pythontex.ins.

Comment: Option 1: find the root of your 'main' texmf tree with `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFMAIN`; option 2: find the root of your 'personal' texmf tree with `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME` (probably `~/texmf`). I refer to your choice as 'TEXMF'. According to `pythontex.pdf` (see p. 8 in my version), you need to move the doc files to `TEXMF/doc/latex/pythontex` (6 files total); the script files to `TEXMF/scripts/pythontex/` (8 files); the source files to `TEXMF/source/latex/pythontex`; and the style file to `TEXMFMAIN|TEXMFLOCAL/tex/latex/pythontex`. Then do `sudo texhash` & create the symlinks.

Comment: When I compile arbitrary .tex with \usepackage{pythontex} it doesn't give any error so i guess we made it. 

Now i tried to compile basic example
\begin{pycode}
def fib(n):
# nth Fibonacci value
a, b = 0, 1
for i in range(n):
a, b = b, a + b
return a
\end{pycode}

It gives ! LaTeX Error: Environment pycode undefined.

Comment: One final note: if you chose to install in TEXMFLOCAL, it will always take priority over a system-installed version (worth remembering for when the Ubuntu repositories begin including newer and newer versions of pythontex).

Comment: \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pythontex}


\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
def fib(n):
# nth Fibonacci value
a, b = 0, 1
for i in range(n):
a, b = b, a + b
return a
\end{pycode}

\end{document}

! LaTeX Error: Environment pycode undefined.
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{pycode}.

Comment: yes it is.
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pythontex/pythontex.sty
(didnt mention: i use texmaker)

Comment: *File List*

...
inputenc.sty 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
utf8.def 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
t1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
ot1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
omsenc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
amsmath.sty 2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features
amstext.sty 2000/06/29 v2.01
amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
amsbsy.sty 1999/11/29 v1.2d
amsopn.sty 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
amsfonts.sty 2009/06/22 v3.00 Basic AMSFonts support
amssymb.sty 2009/06/22 v3.00
pythontex.sty
***********

Comment: i am not sure what do you mean by re-edit my question. 
at the end of my previous reply is part with pythontex.sty. i tried to copy all log but it was to big. however,pythontex.sty is mentioned only once. i will write only this part again:
...
amsbsy.sty 1999/11/29 v1.2d
amsopn.sty 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
amsfonts.sty 2009/06/22 v3.00 Basic AMSFonts support
amssymb.sty 2009/06/22 v3.00
pythontex.sty
***********
)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
1275 strings out of 493485....

Comment: ok, now i understand what you mean by re-edit my question. i will soon.

Comment: `pythontex.sty` does not have a version or date?  That can't be right...

Answer (score 3):

The steps for installing are:

1. Download the package
2. Right click the file and click on `Extract Here`.
3. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run these commands:

   ```
   cd Downloads/pythontex
   latex pythontex.ins
   md ~/texmf
   md ~/texmf/tex
   mv * ~/texmf/tex
   chmod +x ~/texmf/
   ```

And the package will be installed. To compile a file:

```
pdflatex foo.tex
~/texmf/pythontex.py foo.tex
pdflatex foo.tex
```

I installed the package just now with these commands and now it is working for me.

Comment: This is not recommended.  Your `~/texmf` directory should be structured to mirror the TeX Directory Structure of your actual install, which is in fact correctly described in the `pythontex` manual.